# Does this theme look familiar?

Tags: themes, elementary-theme

I just love the theme in this screenshot. Can somebody please give me its name?

[image]

The screenshot is intended to demonstrate how the Axe menu extension looks like. You can find the original post on [k210.org/axemenu](http://k210.org/axemenu).

Comment: The screenshot is intended to demonstrate how the Axe menu extension looks like. You can find the original post on http://k210.org/axemenu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a [Gnome Shell](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-shell) session with a theme *similar to* [Evolve](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Evolve-GTK3-Theme-264780816) (see [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/5-nice-gnome-34-themes-ubuntu-ppa.html) for installing) and [Avant Window Navigator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avant-window-navigator) (at the bottom) running. The menu looks like [Axe Menu](http://k210.org/axemenu/) (installable as [Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/327/axe-menu/)) with [Faenza Icons](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faenza-Icons-173323228).

Comment: I don't think so. Evlove and this theme look generally similar. But some details, which to me are why its more attractive, are different.

Comment: Do you mean the shiny white at the top?

Comment: Exactly. Also the smoothness of the edges, the font effects, the icons the their sizes.

Comment: I was talking about the icons located on the Image Viewer's taskbar. They're so similar but not the same

Comment: If you say so. How about the theme, then? Sorry for being picky :)

Comment: If I knew that ... Try to ask [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/327/axe-menu/), too - there at least he gave a hint at AWN.

Answer (score 4):

The screenshot author [shared his style configuration](http://k210.org/axemenu/#theme):

- Theme: [GrayDay](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=149310)
- Window frame: [modified zukini](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=192749.0;attach=29764)
- Wallpaper - [Farsighted](http://delta909.deviantart.com/art/Farsighted-194935611)